# convergence sequences have decreasing subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)$ converges to $0$ then how can we show that there exists a subsequence $(y_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ such that $|y_{n_k}| < \frac{1}{n_k}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I used the definition of the limit but couldn't find a way to control the upper bound.

Comment: Are you sure this is true?  Consider the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.  This approaches $0$, but no subsequence obeys the condition (as I've parsed it - I could be misunderstanding).  The only interpretation which seems possibly true to me, also seems rather trivial...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you mean $|y_{n_k}|<1/k$ as it's otherwise not true as *user3716267* stated.

For any $k$ choose an $N_k$ such that for $n\geq N_k$, we have $|x_n|<1/k$. We can make sure this sequence of $N_k$'s is increasing since if $N_k$ satisfies to condition above, then any integer larger than $N_k$ does too. Since this sequence is increasing, $x_{N_k}$ is a subsequence of $x_n$. This subsequence, by construction, now satifies $$|x_{N_k}|<1/k.$$